# Displaying sympy equations on matplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

q = [3,5]
t,i = sp.symbols('t,i')
eq = t**2/(q[1]-(t/q[0])**2)
x = np.linspace(0,100,10000)
y=x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Now I want to display the sympy equation "eq" on the plot. I have seen many methods to display the same equation using tex commands, but I specifically want to display the sympy eq. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sympy's [`latex()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.latex.latex) function like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

q = [3,5]
t,i = sp.symbols('t,i')
eq = t**2/(q[1]-(t/q[0])**2)
x = np.linspace(0,100,10000)
y=x**2  
plt.plot(x,y, label=r"$" + f"{sp.latex(eq)}" + r"$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The below also seems to work just as well, why might what you have above be preferred? 

label="$" + sp.latex(eq) + "$"